# Проблема при отправке на печать (PrintTo) через запуск процесса (Process.Start)

Tags: c#, winforms, конвертация, печать

Есть приложение `Windows Forms`, которое работало на машине клиента пару лет. Затем на ту машину было установлено приложение `Imaging` (Древнючая просматривалка изображений) и с ней ассоциированы файлы формата `.tif`. 
Теперь, при обработке приложением файлов `.tif` вылетает ошибка

> Указанному файлу не сопоставлено ни одно приложение для выполнения данной операции

Код приложения такой:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Arguments = "\"Universal Document Converter\"";
info.Verb = "Printto";
info.FileName = file_name;

info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();    //На этой строчке вылетает ошибка
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
p.Dispose();
```

Проверил в `Панели управления -> Программы по умолчанию -> Сопоставление типов файлов или протоколов конкретным программам`, там файлы `.tif` и `.tiff` вообще отсутствовали. Добавил их в тот список и ассоциировал со стандартной просматривалкой Windows. Но ошибка как возникала, так и возникает. Удаление программы `Imaging` тоже не помогло. Что еще можно предпринять?

P.S. Откатить систему не могу, к сожалению.

Comment: Если у вас есть аналогичная система, вы можете подсмотреть обработчик печати для tiff в реестре.

Comment: В переменной `file_name` у Вас по идее должна быть указана программа для запуска, она установлена на ПК?

Comment: @VladD: Скопировал с тестовой машины(на которой приложение работает) на проблемную машину ключи `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tif` и `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tiff`. Не помогло. Других ключей не знаю, подскажите?

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев: Я тоже не знаю, но думаю, что в реестре должно найтись методом пристального взгляда (и поиска). И загляните ещё в HKCU (на _обеих_ машинах).

Comment: @sp7: в `file_name` лежит открываемый файл, в данном случае изображение `tif`. Но так как стоит запуск из под оболочки `info.UseShellExecute = true;`, то картинка должна открыться в ассоциированном приложении по-умолчанию. Но вместо этого выскакивает ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, проверьте, что происходит, когда вы "запускаете" файл с расширением .tif как пользователь. Стандартная просматривалка windows открывается?

Проверьте, не слетела ли настройка "Universal Document Converter" в качестве принтера. Насколько я понимаю, эта программа использует драйвер, распознаваемый как принтер, для конвертации изображения.

Для начала, попробуйте отправить на этот "притер" tif из графического редактора/просматривалки вручную.

Далее, попробуйте выполнить ваш код, но без указания `info.Verb = "PrintTo";`. Открывается просмотр изображения?

Далее, попробуйте автоматизировать выбор принтера, может с названием его что-то не так. Например, там мог второй экземпляр появиться, т.е. циферка в конце.

```
using (PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog())
{
    if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = 
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
        info.FileName = file_name;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.Verb = "PrintTo";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
    }
}
```

Если и это не помогает, то проверьте, не осталось ли после той злополучной программы `Imaging` неправильной настройки для конкретного верба `PrintTo`, искать надо в реестре. Чтобы выяснить это, используйте команы `assoc` и `ftype`. Команда `assoc` показывает, с чем ассоциировано расширение имени файла. Это может быть или программа, или "тип файла".

В командной строке:

```
assoc .tif
assoc .tiff
```

В нормальной ситуации должны возвращать, соответственно:

> .tif=TIFImage.Document
>
> .tiff=TIFImage.Document

Далее, понять что скрывается за ассоциацией с типом `TIFImage.Document` помогает команда `ftype`, опять таки, через командную строку:

```
ftype TIFImage.Document
```

должно возвращать что-то вроде:

> TIFImage.Document=%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1

Если `ftype` такого не возвращает, то надо вручную восстановить ассоциацию и параметры типа `TIFImage.Document` с живой операционки. В часности,

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TIFImage.Document\shell\printto\command
```

значение должно быть похожим на (указано для Windows 10)

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\shimgvw.dll",ImageView_PrintTo /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"
```

Comment: Вручную печатает нормально, из любой просматривалки.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев я написал как предоставить возможность выбрать принтер, попробуйте, может с константой названия что-то не так.

Comment: Проблема как я понимаю не в самом принтере, а в программе, которая отправляет файл на печать. Windows не может выбрать какой программой открыть файл, чтоб отправить на печать.

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев Что происходит, когда вы просто "запускаете" файл с расширением .tif как пользователь? Стандартная просматривалка Windows открывается?

Comment: Да, вручную все открывается и печатается как надо

Comment: Какая операционка у вас?

Comment: Собственно, вопрос вот какой: есть ли у вас в реестре вот такая ассоциация?
ключ: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TIFImage.Document\shell\printto\command
значение: "%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\shimgvw.dll",ImageView_PrintTo /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"

Comment: На компе клиента крутится `Windows 7`. Касательно ассоциаций - ключа `TIFImage.Document` нет не только в `HKCR` но и во всем реестре

Comment: А как в реестре выглядит ассоциация для расширения .tif?

Comment: Собственно в реестр лезть не надо, есть две команды: `assoc .tif` и `ftpye <assoc output>`, напишите, что они возвращают

Comment: Перенес с тестовой машины ключи `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tif`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tiff`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TIFIMage.Document`, теперь комманды `assoc .tif`, `assoc .tiff` и `ftype TIFImage.Document` возвращают тоже самое, как описано у вас в ответе. Но программа так и выдает ошибку

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев проверьте отдельно, что при переносе взялся подраздел `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TIFImage.Document\shell\printto\command`, ftype его не показывает

Comment: Есть такой раздел. Его значение по-умолчанию: `"%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\shimgvw.dll",ImageView_PrintTo /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"`

Comment: Заметил, что если закомментировать строку `info.Verb = "Printto";`, то картинка нормально открывается в стандартной просматривалке. Похоже не в ту сторону мы с вами копали ((

Comment: Вообще `info.Verbs` пустой

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев как раз раздел, про который я последним спрашивал, и определяет поведение для verb=printto

Comment: Приложение каким-то чудом заработало. Все что я сделал - это изменил `info.Verb = "Printto";` на `info.Verb = "printto";`. Теперь не важно в каком регистре написано, и так и так работает. Магия какая-то =) В любом случае спасибо вам, что возились со мной.